# What does Ruby's "class NewClass < ::OtherClass" syntax mean?

Tags: ruby, syntax, namespaces

I know that to use class inheritance in Ruby, the following syntax is used:

```
class MyNewClass < SomeClass
...
end
```

I also know that nesting in namespaces is identified using `::`:

```
class SomeNameSpace::MyNewClass < SomeNameOtherSpace::SomeClass 
...
end
```

However, what does the following syntax mean?

```
class SomeNameSpace::MyNewClass < ::SomeClass 
...
end
```

I expect that `::SomeClass` (so without anything before the `::`)is a shorthand for something, but what exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

`::SomeClass` means `SomeClass` class from top namespace. `::` is specially used to refer the top namespace from deep inside other modules.

Comment: So this means that if I have a module overriding, say,  one of the base classes like `MyHTMLFunModule::String`, I can still refer to the default `String` by using `::String`?